# AUC computation on multilabel classification

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, multiclass-classification

I'm using Tensorflow for an auto-tagging task on audio clips. The problem is actually a multilabel classification problem meaning that each clip can have multiple tags at the same time.

Regarding the model evaluation, I would like to be able to compute the [AUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve) per clip and per tag. My problem is that AUC is basically a metric for binary classification and I don't know how it can be extended to a multilabel problem.

I have found many references of AUC computation on multilabel classification tasks, but none of these explain how to do it.

([An example](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04999))

Comment: How have found any solution for this yet?

Answer (score 1):

AUC (Area under the ROC Curve) can not be calculated for multilabel classification directly.

Multilabel classification metrics have to be converted to a binary problem. The two most common conversions are:

- OvO - One vs One
- OvR - One vs Rest

[sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) discusses this in detail.